# Mac OS X Server: automount encrypted drive before login

Tags: time-machine, osx-server, encryption, automount, hfs+

I have a 4TB `Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)` hard drive hanging off a Mac OS X Lion *(soon to be Mountain Lion)* Server that is dedicated to networked Time Machine backups.

I'd like to be able to mount the drive on startup *before* any user logs in. Right now it's necessary for a user to log in first so the password can be retrieved from the keychain. The reason the drive itself is encrypted is in the event it should ever be separated from the server. I don't mind putting pwd into a boot script (`launchd`?, `fstab`?) of some sort if that's even possible?!?

How to do this? Or is there a better way to encrypt network backups to an OS X Server?

Comment: <...crickets...>